# How to install HP P1108 printer

Tags: printing, hp

Can you please help me in installing Hp P1108 printer? I tried with HPLIP but it is not working. I'm not getting print. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Did you install HPLIP? If yes, what are the steps you followed?

Comment: Access the CUPS (Common Unix Printing System) interface by browsing to `http://localhost:631`.

Comment: I have installed HPLIP from the terminal. Finally, the plugin is not installing for this printer. Please suggest.

Comment: How to operate from the cups, please suggest